# From email couldn't be added in wp_mail in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been trying to add reply to email into the wordpress function `wp_mail`. So, I did as:

```
$subject = 'Inquiry from ' . $_REQUEST['first_name'] . ' ' . $_REQUEST['last_name'];
$headers = 'From: ' . $_REQUEST['first_name'] . ' <' . $_REQUEST['email_address'] . '>' . "\r\n";
if( wp_mail('to@example.com', $subject, $email_template, $header ) ){
    echo "sent";
}
```

In the header section if I add email address as hardcoded it works, i.e.

```
$headers = 'From: ' . $_REQUEST['first_name'] . ' <from@example.com>' . "\r\n";
```

But when I put variable instead of hardcoded, it doesn't work. Please can you tell me anyone how to fix it?

Comment: are you super sure that `$_REQUEST['email_address']` is the write field name on the form ?

Comment: yes, sure. Because I send few fields with email address as email message.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , echo your `$_REQUEST['email_address']` variable before wp_mail function to see weather it is returning the expected value or not.

Secondly ,  See this.

```
if( wp_mail('to@example.com', $subject, $email_template, $header ) )
```

Here you have used `$header`

while you have

```
'$headers' = 'From: ' . $_REQUEST['first_name'] . ' <' . $_REQUEST['email_address'] . '>' . "\r\n";
```

'$headers' Defined for your headers.